How to connect a dockerized mqtt client and a broker
I am trying to connect a mqtt client and the broker. The problem is that they use the same port and docker says that the port is in use.
Connection is refused. This is my dockerfile and docker compose file.
services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2
    container_name: mosquitto
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
      - ./mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    networks:
      - mqtt_network
  modbus:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
    container_name: modbus
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB0:/dev/ttyUSB0
    networks:
      - mqtt_network
networks:
  mqtt_network:
    driver: bridge

FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

ARG VERSION=1.0.0
COPY ./dist/modbus-${VERSION}-py3-none-any.whl .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir modbus-${VERSION}-py3-none-any.whl

RUN mkdir -p /app/logs

EXPOSE 1883

CMD ["modbus"]

persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true


Please update your question with the commands you used to run the compose and the output that was produced (edit as appropriate). Compose networks services (as if each were its own localhost) such that each service can expose ports that may overlap with any other service. Such a port conflict should not be your issue but it's unclear without the aforementioned detail.

ports: - "1883:1883" this maps port 1883 on the Docker host to TCP port 1883 in the container. This will fail if something is already listening on port 1883 on the host (i.e. a local instance of Mosquitto, or another container with a similar mapping), and that may be the cause of the error. You can check by changing the mapping (e.g. 10883:1883 would map port 10883 on the host to 1883 in the container). See this question for more info.

Why is the modbus container also exposing port 1883? As a client it should not need to expose any ports
